# How can I use JSBeautify from the command line?

Tags: python, shell, command-line, js-beautify

I like [jsbeautifier.org](http://jsbeautifier.org/) and I see they have a [github repo](https://github.com/einars/js-beautify) with their code.

The readme has two examples of how to use this tool via the command line:

```
import jsbeautifier
res = jsbeautifier.beautify('your javascript string')
res = jsbeautifier.beautify_file('some_file.js')
```

and:

```
opts = jsbeautifier.default_options()
opts.indent_size = 2
res = jsbeautifier.beautify('some javascript', opts)
```

How can I incorporate this into a script (`myjsbeautify.py`) so that it can accept either `stdin` or an argument (file name) and output to `stdout` ? I also want to use the option to `keep array indentation`.

**Desired syntaxes**

```
cat ugly.js | myjsbeautify.py
```

or

```
myjsbeautify.py ugly.js
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out [this post](http://tobyho.com/2012/03/08/jsbeautifier/) on using JSBeautify with Textmate. It has some good instructions on how to install it on your system. On Mac OS X, I used:

```
cd /tmp
git clone https://github.com/einars/js-beautify.git
cd js-beautify/python
python setup.py install
```

Then you can simply use `js-beautify /path/to/filename.js` to have it run.

Comment: I had to also do `easy_install six`

Answer (score 0):

Your examples are for the usage as a library not command line. If you are trying to create a script yourself that can take arguments and pass it on to JSBeautifier you should take a look at the [argparse](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) module. It has some good examples to get you going.
Example from docs:

```
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('infile', nargs='?', type=argparse.FileType('r'),
...                     default=sys.stdin)
>>> parser.add_argument('outfile', nargs='?', type=argparse.FileType('w'),
...                     default=sys.stdout)
>>> parser.parse_args(['input.txt', 'output.txt'])
Namespace(infile=<_io.TextIOWrapper name='input.txt' encoding='UTF-8'>,
          outfile=<_io.TextIOWrapper name='output.txt' encoding='UTF-8'>)
>>> parser.parse_args([])
Namespace(infile=<_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdin>' encoding='UTF-8'>,
          outfile=<_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' encoding='UTF-8'>)
```

EDIT: you can also use [getopt](http://docs.python.org/library/getopt.html) that is used by the `jsbeautifier.py` itself. If you just want to use `jsbeautifier.py` as a command line tool, read the `usage` function from the source code.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can use the `fileinput` module, which will allow you to read from either standard input or from the files named in the positional arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I just did `pip install jsbeautify` and it added `js-beautify` to my path (`/usr/local/bin/js-beautify`).

You can use it as you'd expect:

```
js-beautify --keep-array-indentation file.json > file.pretty.json
```

And use help to check for more arguments:

```
js-beautify --help
```